# Meteor.js sub templates helpers

Tags: meteor, meteor-helper

This is simplified working template for menus in Meteor application:

```
<template name="menus">
  {{#each menus}}
    {{> menu}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

Template.menus.helpers({
  menus: function () {
    return menus.find();
  }
});

<template name="menu">
  {{title}}
  {{#each menu_items}}
    {{> menu_item}}
  {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>

Template.menu.helpers({
  menu_items: function () {
    return menu_items.find({
      menuId: this._id
    });
  }
});

<template name="menu_item">
  <div class="b-menu-item">
    <a class="b-menu-item-link" href="{{link}}">{{title}}</a>
  </div>
</template>
```

Now I need to add `menu_level` template to implement infinite sub menu items rendering:

```
<template name="menus">
  {{#each menus}}
    {{> menu}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

Template.menus.helpers({
  menus: function () {
    return menus.find();
  }
});

<template name="menu">
  {{title}}
  {{#if menu_items}}
    {{> menu_level}}
  {{/if}}
  </div>
</template>

<template name="menu_level">
  <div class="b-menu-level">
  {{#each menu_items}}
    {{> menu_item}}
  {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>

Template.menu_level.helpers({
  menu_items: function () {
    return menu_items.find({
      menuId: this._id
    });
  }
});

<template name="menu_item">
  <div class="b-menu-item">
    <a class="b-menu-item-link" href="{{link}}">{{title}}</a>
    {{#if menu_items}}
      {{> menu_level}}
    {{/if}}
  </div>
</template>

Template.menu_item.helpers({
  menu_items: function () {
    return menu_items.find({
      menuItemId: this._id
    });
  }
});
```

However, I can't get menu items via this helper:

```
Template.menu_level.helpers({
  menu_items: function () {
    return menu_items.find({
      menuId: this._id
    });
  }
});
```

How to force `this._id` to relate with `menu <- menu_level` not just `menu_level` that doesn't have `_id`?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_parentdata

you can use `Template.parentData(index)`

simple code

```
<template name="menu">
  {{title}}
  {{#if menu_items}}
    {{> menu_level}}
  {{/if}}
  </div>
</template>

<template name="menu_level">
  <div class="b-menu-level">
  {{#each menu_items}}
    {{> menu_item}}
  {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>
```

and in

```
Template.menu_level.helpers({
  menu_items: function () {
    var data=Template.parentData(1);
    console.log(data)
 //check whether you are getting exact data otherwise change the index to Template.parentData(2) and check
     var menuId=data._id;//this is equivalent to {{../this._id}}
    return menu_items.find({
      menuId: menuId
    });
  }
});
```

or you can pass data to helper like(not sure though)

```
<template name="menu_level">
      <div class="b-menu-level">
      {{#each menu_items ../_id}}
        {{> menu_item}}
      {{/each}}
      </div>
    </template>


Template.menu_level.helpers({
  menu_items: function (menuid) {
    return menu_items.find({
      menuId: menuid
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I have to add one more helper—to `menu` template. So now `menu_level` has the same context as menu.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Sasikanth answer.

I have to add one more helper—to `menu` template:

```
Template.menu.helpers({
  menu_items: function () {
    return menu_items.find({
      menuId: this._id
    });
  }
});
```

So now `menu_level` has the same context as menu.

Final code:

```
<template name="menus">
  {{#each menus}}
    {{> menu}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

Template.menus.helpers({
  menus: function () {
    return menus.find();
  }
});

<template name="menu">
  {{title}}
  {{#if menu_items}}
    {{> menu_level}}
  {{/if}}
  </div>
</template>

Template.menu.helpers({
  menu_items: function () {
    return menu_items.find({
      menuId: this._id
    });
  }
});

<template name="menu_level">
  <div class="b-menu-level">
  {{#each menu_items}}
    {{> menu_item}}
  {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>

Template.menu_level.helpers({
  menu_items: function () {
    return menu_items.find({
      menuId: this._id
    });
  }
});

<template name="menu_item">
  <div class="b-menu-item">
    <a class="b-menu-item-link" href="{{link}}">{{title}}</a>
    {{#if menu_items}}
      {{> menu_level}}
    {{/if}}
  </div>
</template>

Template.menu_item.helpers({
  menu_items: function () {
    return menu_items.find({
      menuItemId: this._id
    });
  }
});
```